# Is this mold growing behind duct tape that's holding vapor barrier to concrete foundation?

Tags: concrete, foundation, mold, crawlspace, vapor-barrier

We put a vapor barrier down in our crawl space. Some parts of the perimeter were not completely sealed, so a few months ago, I used a clear duct tape to attach the vapor barrier to the concrete foundation wall. I was worried that it may fall off due to moisture from concrete, but I just took a look today and it is still very much in place. However, I noticed dark brown dots behind the duct tape, right along the vapor barrier. Is this mold? Should I be worried?
[image]
[image]

Comment: does it scrape off easily, is it soft

Comment: It's on the wall side of the tape. Should I remove the tape and try scraping it?

Comment: I suspect that it's minerals that were dissolved in moisture coming up through concrete and then left there as the moisture evaporated.

Comment: Do you sleep in your crawl space?